# How to create inner and outside shadow effect button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, sass

I tried to create a CSS effect button ditto same as below I provide image, (ignore icons) But try but not getting same like results is there any way to create a perfect same CSS button?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

here is my button code below
of my HTML button

```css
.my-bt{
display:block;
position:relative;
background: linear-gradient(310deg, #dcb7e0, #dbdaef);
padding:10px;
text-align:center;
border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='my-bt'>Hello World</div>
```

Please Help me to create 101% Same ditto button
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/omwyj.jpg

Comment: [This may help.](https://html-css-js.com/css/generator/box-shadow/)

Comment: This design is known as Neumorphism. https://neumorphism.io/

Comment: This might help also https://codepen.io/dasshounak/pen/rNMjmaO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. We have used multiple `box-shadow` as per your requirements.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/ry2sqpue/

for more reference you may use the link also: https://codepen.io/yudizsolutions/pen/mdrKdVa

```css
body {
  background-color: #f1f0f5;
}

.my-bt {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 18px 0 #e3deed, -6px -6px 18px 0 rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  margin: 20px 10px;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-bt">
  Hello World
</div>
```